# Similar to Fodor lemma

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\lambda>\aleph_0$ be a regular cardinal such that $S \subseteq \lambda$ is not a stationary subset. Prove that there exists a regressive function $f:S \to \lambda$ such that $|f^{-1}(\alpha)|<\lambda$ for every $\alpha<\lambda$.

Comment: It seems like it's a sort of converse to Fodor's lemma in fact.

Comment: Here's a hint: That $S$ is not stationary means that there is a club set $C$ that misses $S$. Notice that club sets are closed and hence contain their limits. Can you define some function $f:S\to C$ that you can guarantee that is regressive and takes any value only for bounded many elements of $\lambda$?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Yes, it is the converse of Fodor's lemma, and therefore this gives a complete characterization of stationary sets using regressive functions: $S$ is stationary if and only if every regressive function from $S$ to $\lambda$ is constant on a stationary subset of $S$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If $C\subseteq\lambda$ is closed, and $\alpha\in\lambda\setminus C$, the set $C\cap\alpha=\{\xi\in C:\xi<\alpha\}$ has a maximum element.

Comment: So using Apostolos's hint above as well, if $C$ is a club set that misses $S$ we can define $f:S \to C$ by $f(\alpha)$ being the maximum element of $C \cap \alpha$. The function is regressive clearly. And also $|f^{-1}(\beta)|$ has to be bounded because $C$ is unbounded, so if $\alpha$ is large enough, $\beta$ stops being the maximum of $C \cap \alpha$. Does that sound right?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Sounds fine.